# TagLib outputs wrong encoding

Tags: grails, taglib, html-encode

I'm using a TagLib, but it is presenting a weird behaviour, instead of output character like `<`, `"`, and `>` it outputs `&lt;`, `&quot;`, and  `&gt;`.

the code:

```
class LoginTagLib {
static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
//static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
def loginControl = 
{
    if(session.user)
    {
        out << "Hello ${session.user.name}"
        out << """[${link(action:"logout", controller:"user"){"Logout"}}]"""
    }
    else
    {
        out << """[${link(action:"login", controller:"user"){"Login"}}]"""
    }
}
```

}

in the .gsp I've got

```
<g:loginControl />
```

When I open the page I have:

```
Hello Jane Smith[<a href="/Blogito/user/logout">Logout</a>]
```

but the page's source code is:

```
<div id="loginHeader">
Hello Jane Smith[&lt;a href=&quot;/Blogito/user/logout&quot;&gt;Logout&lt;/a&gt;]
</div>
```

I've tried using `.encodeAsHTML()`, `decodeHTML`, `.replace('&gt;', '<')` and nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this line:

<strike>static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']</strike>

and try again.

Answer (score 6):

You could also tell it to send it as a text(no encoding that is)
 change

```
static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
```

to

```
static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'text']
```